# If I close the Epic Launcher during a download, will the download fail?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

I am downloading Fortnite; I want to exit the launcher, but I dont want to lose the progress on my download. If I exit the launcher, will the download fail? Currently, it is paused. Is it possible for me to shutdown my PC and then resume the download later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can close the Epic Games Launcher without having to worry that you'd have to download everything from the start.

All downloads will be paused once you exit the launcher. When you launch it later, you will have the option for resuming the download.

Comment: It work for me for 6 days but after that download restated.

Comment: Might be caused by an update that came out during that period