# Downloading in Epic Games Launcher starts from 0% after pause and reboot, why?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

I'm downloading GTA V. After 20gb / 100gb I paused my download for restarting my pc. Then download restarts from 0%.

Why this could happen? Can I restart my PC during downloads without losing progress?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I close the Epic Launcher during a download, will the download fail?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336244/if-i-close-the-epic-launcher-during-a-download-will-the-download-fail)

Comment: @arghtype the answer to that question says the download should pause. He's having a different problem where his downloads completely restart.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I couldn't reproduce the issue you're having. I hope you'll get the answer you're looking for eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pause or exit Epic Games launcher when you are still downloading. If the Wi-Fi is off, restart your PC. If you want to shutdown your PC, shut it down without pausing the game or exiting Epic Games. This worked for me.